# How can i save to csv file about Variable importance using DALEX package, model_part() with python

Tags: python, dalex

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXyFC.jpg)

I want to extract the feature importance using DALEX package, but i don't know how to export the results to save that results with format excel file

how should i do?

i did below method, but it didn't work

```
model.model_parts().to_csv(',,,,')
```

Comment: What is the model? And what is the error message you are getting?